# Выборка блоков в зависимости от параметров в data

Tags: jquery

Есть код:

```js
function Values() {
  var val = $("#values").val();
  if( val != 0 ){
    $('.game').fadeOut();
    $('.game[data-value~="'+val+'"]').fadeIn();
  }else{
    $('.game').fadeIn();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="Values()" id="values">
    <option value="0">All</option>
    <option value="arcade">Arcade</option>
    <option value="quest">Quest</option>
    <option value="sim">Simulators</option>
    <option value="2">Для 2-х игроков</option>
    <option value="3">Для 3-х игроков</option>
    <option value="4">Для 4-х игроков</option>
</select>

<div data-value="arcade 4" class="game">arcade 4</div>
<div data-value="arcade 1" class="game">arcade 1</div>
<div data-value="quest 1" class="game">quest 1</div>
<div data-value="quest 4" class="game">quest 4</div>
<div data-value="arcade 3" class="game">arcade 3</div>
<div data-value="sim 2" class="game">sim 2</div>
<div data-value="sim 4" class="game">sim 4</div>
```

Первая строка выводит все элементы, остальные в зависимости от параметров в data (их может быть несколько)
Подскажите как заменить теги option\select на  срабатывающие при клике. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: я ничего не понял

Comment: Сейчас выборка производится при изменении select, нужно что б производилась при клике на div, те <option> надо заменить на <div> ну и как то сам скрипт перенастроить.